# VSS Error 0x8004231F

Tags: windows-7, backup, vmware, vss

I'm trying to convert my powered-on Win7 Ultimate SP1 to a VMWare Virtual Machine using Converter Standalone. Problem is, the conversion fails because of a VSS error:

`FAILED: The VSS snapshots cannot be stored because there is not enough space on the source volumes or because the source machine does not have any NTFS volumes. Error code: 2147754783 (0x8004231F).`

After hours of research, it's clear that there isn't enough space on the C: drive for VSS do do its job. But I have plenty of free space on other drives (all NTFS). Is there any way I can force VSS to use another drive for its work? My `vssadmin` doesn't seem to have the `add` command used in some posts to fix a similar problem affecting servers, so I'm really lost.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is truly no solution to the above. The only suggestion Microsoft could come up with was to make some more space in the drive...

To solve the initial problem I did the following:

1. Create an image with True Image 2013;
2. Converted it with the free StarWind Converter (http://www.starwindsoftware.com/download-starwind-converter) to wmdk;
3. Create a new virtual machine (custom settings) and use the above vmdk file as the hard disk.

Comment: Update 2018: Converting True Image to VMware is not supported by the current versions. Instead I went back to create more space on the partition that causes the error (in my case it was the System-Reserved partition, I ended up temp moving the asrm.bin file from the bootwiz-folder on that partition).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Win7 x64 PC.

The problem is the "System Reserved" partition (100MB): too small.

I used free Minitool Partition Wizard to resize the System Reserved:

1. Resize C: leaving 1Gb free on the left side
2. Resize System Reserved to 400Mb
3. Resize C: to fit the extra free space on the left side

After the apply and reboot the P2V conversion was OK.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the recovery partition. If it says 0 bytes free, then assign it a drive letter, open it and see what is taking the space. If you don't see anything, google how to delete journal files because that might be the problem. In my case, the problem was a 73 mb folder from Kaspersky, which left 0 bytes free.  Deleted that, removed the assigned drive letter and the VSS shadow copy error vanished.  I'm 70 percent through the backup.